# arrogate vs arrogate to

Tags: verbs

Can the verb **arrogate** stand alone? http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/arrogate only publicises **arrogate + to**.

For example, would it be right to omit **to** in [the following by Thomas Jefferson in July 11 1819](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22arrogate%20to%20myself%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=10&sr=):

> my opinions, given without intention or suspicion have been sometimes handed to the public, but always with out my consent, except in one or two special cases. I hope therefore you will be so kind as to accept of this my apology and reason why, after I shall have read the book, I shall not **arrogate to** myself the office of saying to the public whether they should read it or not.

Comment: Thomas Jefferson was writing almost 200 years ago; the syntax has changed since then, and writing style has changed even more. However, though sentences as florid as this are no longer written (at least not often), _arrogate_ still takes a receiver _to_-phrase (with a reflexive object, most likely), in almost every case. It's not required with _arrogation_, though; you can only cram so many arguments into a nominalization. So _his/the arrogation of power_ is fine.

Comment: @LePressentiment - I think you have in mind 's'arroger' in French or the Italian "arrogarsi". They are quite common verbs in those languages. In English it no longer is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both *arrogate* and *arrogate oneself to*  can be  used but they are no longer common expression:

[To arrogate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Arrogate): tr. v.

> 1. To take or claim for oneself without right; appropriate: *Presidents who have arrogated the power of Congress to declare war* . See Synonyms at appropriate.
> 2. To ascribe on behalf of another in an unwarranted manner.

To arrogate to oneself: (phrasal verb)

> arrogate to yourself something (formal)
>   to claim or take something that you have no right to, 
>   *I do not arrogate to myself the right to decide.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arrogate%20to%20oneself%2Carrogate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carrogate%20to%20oneself%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carrogate%3B%2Cc0) shows that both expression are no longer common.